# Multiprocessing in Python - Concurrence

Tags: python, multiprocessing, multicore

I have a simple class ImageData, to create some Images using Shepard Interpolation. I have to generate more then 50 images, so I though I could parallelized this. I've tried this (I've never worked with multiprocessing before, so, sorry if I made something stupid), already applying what @Alfe taught me:

```
class ImageData(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height, range_min=-1, range_max=1):
        """
        The ImageData constructor
        """
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #The values range each pixel can assume
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max
        self.data = []
        for i in range(width):
            self.data.append([0] * height)

    def shepard_interpolation(self, queue, seeds=10):
        """
        Perform a Shepard shepard_interpolation
        :param queue
        :param seeds
        """
        points = []
        f = []
        for s in range(seeds):
            # Generate a pixel position
            pos_x = random.randrange(self.width)
            pos_y = random.randrange(self.height)

            # Save the f(x,y) data
            x = Utils.translate_range(pos_x, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max)
            y = Utils.translate_range(pos_y, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max)
            z = Utils.function(x, y)
            points.append([x, y])
            f.append(z)

        for i in range(self.width):
            xt = (Utils.translate_range(i, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max))
            for j in range(self.height):
                yt = (Utils.translate_range(j, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max))
                self.data[i][j] = Utils.shepard_euclidian(points, f, [xt, yt], 3)
        queue.put(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=ImageData.shepard_interpolation, args=(ImageData(50, 50), q,))    for _ in range(2)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print "Finish"
```

The problem is 'cause when I call passing range(2), everything works, but when I try with range(3), it never ends (my code never reaches the 'Finish' print) and I don't know why. And, in my case, I have to generate more then 50 images, and I don't know how I could achieve this. I have a processor Core 2 Duo.

EDIT:

I tried to comment the `queue.put(self)` and it works. But I have to receive the result, and this is the only way that I know so far to achieve this. I also don't get why with two processes it works.
Any idea about what I could do to solve this? I guess the erros is in `shepard_euclidian` method. But I couldn't find it until now. This is this function:

```
def shepard_euclidian(x, z, p, u):
    n = len(x)
    d = [0.0] * n
    for i in range(n-1):
        pi = x[i]
        d[i] = math.pow(math.hypot(pi[0]-p[0], pi[1]-p[1]), u)
    w = [0.0] * n
    sw = 0.0
    for i in range(n-1):
        w[i] = 1.0
        for k in range(n-1):
            if i != k:
                w[i] *= d[k]
        sw += w[i]
    for i in range(len(w)-1):
        if sw != 0.0:
            w[i] /= sw
        else:
            w[i] = 0.0
    c = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        c += (w[i] * z[i])
    return c
```

When I try this:

```
for i in range(self.width):
        xt = (Uts.Utils.translate_range(i, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max))
        for j in range(self.height):
            yt = (Uts.Utils.translate_range(j, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max))
            data = Uts.Utils.shepard_euclidian(points, f, [xt, yt], 3)
    queue.put(data)
```

It works. But this is not what I want.

And if I try this:

```
   aux = ImageData(50, 50)
   for i in range(self.width):
        xt = (Uts.Utils.translate_range(i, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max))
        for j in range(self.height):
            yt = (Uts.Utils.translate_range(j, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max))
            aux[x][y] = Uts.Utils.shepard_euclidian(points, f, [xt, yt], 3)
   self.data = aux
   queue.put(self.data)
```

It doesn't work. I really don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to memorize *all* processes (ugly called `k` in your look) and join *all* of them in a second loop.  Maybe this solves your issues at hand.

And please use a better name:

```
processes = [
  Process(target=ImageData.shepard_interpolation, args=(ImageData(50, 50), q,))
  for _ in range(3) ]
for process in processes:
    process.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

EDIT:

I've got a minimal version of your code which works without problems on my machine:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import *

class ImageData(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        pass

    def shepard_interpolation(self, queue, seeds=10):
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        print self.pid, "queue put"
        queue.put(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    processes = [ Process(
      target=ImageData.shepard_interpolation, args=(ImageData(50, 50), q))
        for _ in range(10) ]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    results = []
    for process in processes:  # just to have the correct amount of results
        results.append(q.get())
    print '---------Out--------'
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    print [ result.pid for result in results ]
```

Comment: You should try to find out where the processes hang.  Introduce a bunch of `print` statements, I propose.  Each should print `os.getpid()` and the current line number (or other descriptive statements).  Maybe you get enlightened when you find out at which statement the children and the parent wait for something.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that all processes get at the last line of the interpolation method. But it seems to me that not all of them get to the join statement. Sorry if this is idiot, this is the first time that I try to work with multiprocessing and to learn it.

Comment: Only the *parent* is supposed to `join` its children.  Also, the code as I see it does not let the children come to any `join` (so it is correct).  As a consequence I'm wondering what you are talking about.

Comment: Anyway, you posted only debug output for cases 2 and 3; more itneresting would be the output for the case 4 which does not behave properly.  Also:  please do not split the debug output onto two lines.  We are dealing with concurrencies and between the two print statements another process might do output.  This also can happen if we do it in one line (then the lines get garbled) but it is far less likely.

Comment: And also please to debug output in the loop for `join`ing every child.  Print the `process` in that debug output.

Comment: Ok, but with 3 process is not working anymore (I update the text), 'cause of this I put the result.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice (it's hard to find such changes, so a hint is appreciated ;-)   Then I really would have a look at the joining in the parent process.  At least one process does not seem to be joined properly, so the parent hangs.

Comment: I've tested with, 3, 4, 5 processes... I always get 2 process joined and no more than this...

Comment: I've reduced your code (there is a lot in there which is not related to the multiprocessing) to a minimal example on ho to do it, and I do not get any problems.  I will add my minimal code in my answer above.  Maybe you can first ensure that my minimal example also runs flawlessly on your machine, and then expand it step by step with your real production code to see when the problem appears.

Comment: Everything worked pretty well. I'll work on it now to see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you! xD

Comment: If the call to `shepard_euclidian` does not terminate, find out which line in the code you pasted is reached last (insert debug messages again, or use a debugger, but that would be a new can of worms, especially in multiprocessing).

Comment: And you should split the computation and the assignment if this is unclear: `tmp = Utils.shepard_euclidian(points, f, [xt, yt], 3)` and `self.data[i][j] = tmp` in two separate steps.  Maybe then you can time the call and debug-print its result.  I have no idea why assigning the value to `self.data[i][j]` should pose a problem, but I also don't like thinking about this until it is clear _that_ this is the case.

Comment: Hi @Alfe. `shepard_euclidian` finishes, I tested it. Split this assignment was my first try, but it didn't work either. It seems to me that the problem is in `queue.put(self)`, 'cause when I comment it, even with the direct assignment mentioned before, everything works, but, of course, I have no results in this case. Thank you.

Comment: It's weird. I did another test now and assigned `1` for each `self.data[i][j]`. And it worked. So I guess the problem is really in that function.

Comment: I really don't know. It must be something really stupid. Every process seems to leave the method with the correct number of iterations (width x height x number_of_process).

Comment: When I change the image size, not all process join to the parent thread. I guess that you right and in this case the `shepard_euclidian` it's not finishing for somehow.

Comment: I think that maybe two threads are trying to write in the queue at the same time. Do you think that this may be the problem?

Comment: It's not likely to be a problem when the processes (not threads) are writing at the same time; they are supposed to do this and the Queue is supposed to do all the synchronization necessary.  Have you instead split computation and assignment?  If so, which is the hanging one?  If it is the computation, then maybe check where in the computation it is hanging.

Comment: I've noticed one thing: If you look at my code, I was `join` before `q.get()`. For some reason, I've put the `q.get()` before `join` and it worked. But this doesn't make sense for me. Indeed, I made some tests with simple examples (like parallelized sum), changing this order and it worked in both ways. Besides, if I do `q.get()` before `join`, it's not possible to try to get something before the threads had end?

Comment: It could be that the queue is limited in size and so the putting of the value halts the child until the parent has taken sth from the queue and thus made room for more putting.  Seems reasonable.

Comment: This would also explain why I could not reproduce the problem; my examples are using little data, yours are using (maybe) lots of data and thus fill up the queue faster.

Comment: Hi, @Alfe. What is the difference between using this approach, with N (number of images process) and a pool of workers? If the number of image is large, 1000, all will create 1000 processes. Does this make sense?!

Comment: A 1000 processes will eat up all (and more than that) of your memory and thus slow down the system extremely.  Also, doing the tasks switches from one process to another will take more and more time.  Do not use more than a few hundred processes at a time, and depending on their memory usage, much less.  I propose to run some tests to find an optimal number of concurrent processes.  Typically more than you have processor cores only makes sense if the processes are often waiting for external I/O.

Comment: Yes, this is what I though. I guess is better to use Pool, so. But reading here (http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multithreading#module-multiprocessing.pool), it seems that I can't kill the master process. Also, I didn't find any example using Pool where I can pass multiple parameters as I do with a Process. Asking this 'cause now I have a method really slow if two for (nested), which can be parallelized (each calculus is independent), but doesn't make any sense apply what I did here, generating a large number of process.